# Change color of group of MKPinAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have several annotation pins (aprox 700) in a MapView. Is there any way I can select from an UITableView a row and change the color of a group of pins? Lets say each row representing a group of pins.. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You set your pin colours in the `MKMapViewDelegate` method `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`.  If you use `MKPinAnnotationView`, you are limited to three colours (red, green purple), which is efficient if you have lots of pins.

If you want, you can return a custom view, possibly a `UIImageView`, which can be any colour you like.

Setting the values in a tableView: that's up to you.  I'd probably pass it in my custom annotation object.

If you want to change an existing view, you could save the views in a `NSSet` or other collection class as you create them, or you could remove the annotation objects and re-add them to your map.

Comment: I would suggest you save the views as they are created (in the above method), and change the colours that way.